# Unable to pass variable to a bash command in python

Tags: python, bash, azure

I am trying to pass a python variable to a bash command like this:

```
subscriptionId = "xxxxx"
command = " az account show -s $subscriptionId"
subprocess.check_output(command)
```

I get there following error:

```
error : az account show: error: argument --subscription/-s: expected one argument
```

Comment: It looks like bash thinks `$subscriptionId` is an environment variable. In your Python code, you should explicitly reference the `subscriptionId` variable (as if it were a Python variable, not a bash variable), since the command is just a string in Python and that's how you're passing it to the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the variable command is just a string you could simply do this.

```
subscriptionId = "xxxxx"
command = " az account show -s " + subscriptionId
subprocess.check_output(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a Python variable like `subscriptionId = "xxxxx"` does not magically place it in your environment, much less pass it to a subprocess. You need to do that interpolation yourself:

```
command = f"az account show -s {subscriptionId}"
```

If you *really* want to use environment variables, add the variable you want and enable shell expansion:

```
subscriptionId = ...
env = os.environ.copy()
env['subscriptionId'] = subscriptionId
command = "az account show -s ${subscriptionId}"
subprocess.check_output(command, env=env, shell=True)
```

Alternatively, you can mess with your own process environment:

```
subscriptionId = ...
os.environ['subscriptionId'] = subscriptionId
command = "az account show -s ${subscriptionId}"
subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

These options are, in my opinion, not recommended, since they raise all the security issues that `shell=True` brings with it, while providing you with no real advantage.